# AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'img_to_array'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have added following libraries and half part of the code is executing. In second half I get this error.

Libraries added:

```
#importing libraries
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.utils import img_to_array
```

Error:
AttributeError: module 'keras.preprocessing.image' has no attribute 'img_to_array'

I was following this code and changes the libraries too still can't resolve the issue.
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/k-means-clustering-and-transfer-learning-for-image-classification/

Comment: which version of tensorflow you are using?. You may want to try the old way of calling it `from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has now moved to `tf.keras.utils.img_to_array`. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/img_to_array)